# Typoscript modify a field:variable

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have this typoscript:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {

    3cols.outerWrap = <div>|</div>
    3cols.outerWrap.override.insertData = 1
    3cols.outerWrap.override = <div id="{field:tx_cewrap_id_input}" class="{field:tx_cewrap_class_input} {field:tx_cewrap_class_select}">|</div>
    3cols.outerWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = tx_cewrap_active
}
```

Which makes sure a wrapper is made around a certain element. The following html is generated as an example:

```
<div id="" class="full-box full-box-features container pt-75,pb-75"></div>
```

As you can see there is a comma separated string inserted as "tx_cewrap_class_select". With the `{field:tx_cewrap_class_select}` part:

```
pt-75,pb-75
```

But i want the comma to be a space character so the classes work in html

Now I know about the [split](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Split.html) option

But how do I fix the code, just need somehow to remove the comma! That's it :)

Thanks in advance for any response I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by comma and join with a space, but in this case it might be easier just to replace the comma by space:

```
10 = TEXT
10.replacement {
    1 {
       search = ,
       replace.char = 32
    }
}
```

And here the solution with split. it should be obvious why not to use:

```
10 = TEXT
10.split {
    token = ,
    cObjNum = 1 || 2
    1.current = 1
    2.current = 1
    2.noTrimWrap = | ||
}
```

**Hint**:
on `TEXT` you can use stdWrap functions immediately,
in other context you might need an explicit `.stdWrap`:

```
10.stdWrap.replacement {

10.stdWrap.split {
```

---

Either you prepare your values into a register for later use, or you split your override value into a COA. You even might use the replacement on the whole override value in case you are sure no other comma might be needed.

**COA-Solution**:
(don't forget the noTrimWrap for `20` otherwise the classes are appended without space)

```
override.cObject = COA
override.cObject {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value <div id="{field:tx_cewrap_id_input}" class="{field:tx_cewrap_class_input} 
    10.insertData = 1

    20 = TEXT
    20.field = tx_cewrap_class_select
    20.replacement {
        1 {
           search = ,
           replace.char = 32
        }
        noTrimWrap= | ||
    }

    30 = TEXT
    30.value = ">|</div>
}
```

Comment: Yes !! This was almost perfect for my situation: the COA part. Just needed a minor tweak and it worked. You are the typoscript endboss!